# Trigger a stored proc and log details

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a trigger that executes when insert

```
create table audy(id int,stat varchar(10),psq)
insert into audy(1,ps,2014-01-01,2014-01-02)
insert into audy(2,ss,2014-02-05,2014-02-06)




--trigger
create trigger audytrigg After insert on aud 
for each row execute ProLayer()



--stored proc
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ProLayer() 
    RETURNS trigger AS $Agg_Layer$
    BEGIN

    if New.id=1 then


    insert into agg(id,sales,qty)
    select id,sum(sales),sales(qty) from perf a inner join audy b on a.id=b.id 
    where a.id between b.start and b.end

    end
```

Now if the job is successful then I have to insert into Aud(stat,psq) values('su',now) and if fail Rollback.

How can I do this in postgres?

Comment: any help? any links? thanks!

Comment: patience, patience. Where did you get stuck doing this? You say "if the job is successful". What job exactly? The `insert`? How can it fail? How do you tell if it failed?

Comment: Success if the `insert is success` and log into `audit log` and fail..due to some violation.. may not be the case..but I need to include in the code.. or rollback ... the job is my stored proc..  for version 9.3.9

Comment: Right, so you need to read the manual on how PL/PgSQL functions work and how their error handling works then come back to this. You can't do explicit rollback from within a function, and exceptions are thrown on errors that will cause a rollback unless explicitly caught. So all you need to do, by the sounds, is add a second insert for the audit log.